# do something when mouse hovers over each select option in the list (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, select, hover

I want run a function when the mouse hovers over each select option in the list.

In this example what I have is a select with a list of colours and I want the background of a separate element in the document to change to the colour as I hover over each option. I have it at the moment so it changes to the correct colour once selected but I'd really like it to show as I hover over the options before I actually select. Can I get an event listener to recognise this event?

I'm aware I can probably manage this with a custom dropdown but I really want to be able to do it with the native  options.

So far i've tried:

```
function showSelectValue(e) { 
    console.log(e.target.value) // or other function...
}

itemid('select').addEventListener('mouseover',showSelectValue,false);
```

but this is only firing when I hover over the closed menu. So no good...

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done because dropdown menues are rendered by browsers - while they are using the option element to render the menu, of course, what you see on the screen is no longer a DOM element, but a browser's rendition of it.

Some browsers might accept some forms of `option` styling, etc... but your safest and probably the best move would be to create your own implementation of the dropdown menu.

---

Something like this (a super-super simple version I quickly sketched for you):

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c');
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
var options = menu.getElementsByTagName('p')

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  options[i].style.display = 'none';
  options[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    c.style.backgroundColor = this.getAttribute('data-color');
  })
}

menu.addEventListener('click', function(){
  for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    options[i].style.display = options[i].style.display != 'none' ? 'none' : 'block';
  }
})
```

```css
#c {height: 150px; width: 150px; float: right;}
#menu {display: inline-block; border: 1px inset #999; padding: 4px; cursor: pointer; box-shadow: 0 0 8px #aaa;}
#menu:hover {border: 1px inset #333}
```

```html
<div id="c">Color</div>
<div id="menu">Menu
  <p data-color="yellow">Yellow</p>
  <p data-color="red">Red</p>
  <p data-color="green">Green</p>
  <p data-color="blue">Dark Blue</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, sadly, the browser-makers made something so simple way too complicated.