# Properly display value from a listbox into a DIV element via Javascript onmouseover event handler

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display the selected value of a list-box in `<div>` tag with below code. The value is shown in a *div* element, but selecting another value from the combobox does not shows the new value properly.

Please help me I'm new to JavaScript and trying to learn, it will be very helpfull to me.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Demo GetSelectOptionData</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="demoForm">
    <select name="demoSelect" onmouseover="showData(this.value)" size="5">
      <option value="A">Option 1</option>
      <option value="B">Option 2</option>
      <option value="C">Option 3</option>
    </select>
  </form>
  <p id="secondP">&nbsp;</p>
  <script>
    function showData() {
      var theSelect = demoForm.demoSelect;
      var secondP = document.getElementById('secondP');
      var thirdP = document.getElementById('thirdP');
      var thirdp = "this static value";

      secondP.innerHTML = ('Its value is: ' + theSelect[theSelect.selectedIndex].value);

    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not sure if what you need is possible (without creating a pseudo-select), the selected answer here may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31910038/do-something-when-mouse-hovers-over-each-select-option-in-the-list-javascript

Comment: i want to be in select list box only

Comment: Do you mean that when you click the option it doesn't change the div immediately? Can you clarify what you expect should happen with what the mouse is doing (hovering over, clicking, etc) and which specific element you are interacting with (the select tag, the option value tag, etc). Need a better idea of what is happening vs what should happen.

Comment: my requirement is when we mouseover on select option the select value has to be display in Div element  but select list box when we are clicking one option to another it not showing immediately the value  ,

Comment: First fix your html it is so wrong.

Comment: I think I have a better idea of what you are trying to accomplish- take a look at my answer below. You might need to modify it if your requirements aren't what I am thinking, but it should help enough to get you there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Demo GetSelectOptionData</title>
        </head>
    <body>
    <form id="demoForm">
        <select name="demoSelect" id="demoSelect" onchange="showData(this.value)" size="5">
            <option onmouseover="showHoverData(this.value)" value="A">Option 1</option>
            <option onmouseover="showHoverData(this.value)" value="B">Option 2</option>
            <option onmouseover="showHoverData(this.value)" value="C">Option 3</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <p id="secondP">&nbsp;</p>
    <p id="thirdP">&nbsp;</p>
    <script>
      function showData(val){
        secondP.innerHTML = ('Its value is: ' + val);
      }  
      function showHoverData(val){
        thirdP.innerHTML = ('Hovering over: ' + val);
      }  
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Answers which explain the changes made to code are downvoted less often than those which simply say "Try this" and a bunch of uncommented code.